# How to know last shutdown reason from command line?

Tags: shutdown, hardware

I have Ubuntu server installed and it is headless. From time to time I am finding it is off. How to know the reason of shutdown? May it is a cat who presses poweroff button? Or may be it is hardware failure?

Comment: Well the system will not know who pressed power off button. You need to check the logs and common causes are over heating. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9819/how-to-find-out-from-the-logs-what-caused-system-shutdown and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53252/how-to-read-the-messages-during-power-off

Comment: I don't need to know who pressed the button, I need to know what is namely that botton...

Comment: The links above should help you find out.